# Failed to resolve "Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WebViewRenderer" after upgrading to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just upgraded to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012 and when trying to build the iOS project I get the following error:

```
Error MT2002: Failed to resolve "Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WebViewRenderer" reference from "Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" (MT2002)
```

I am not using any references to WebViewRenderer anywhere. I have also looked at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809) and added the mtouch argument, still the same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I was using a package that needed to be updated (MR.Gestures).

I found out by typing `WebViewRender` in a class without the `using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS`. There were 2 resolve options:
`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WebViewRender`
and
`MR.Gesture.WebViewRender`
So that was my hint. Updated MR.Gestures and the problem was solved.

Comment: nice to here that you found the nuget package that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

[According to the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#performance), this class is removed in Xamarin.Forms 5:

> In Xamarin.Forms 5.0, the WebViewRenderer class has been removed.
> Therefore, Xamarin.Forms 5.0 doesn't contain a reference to the
> UIWebView control.

Comment: but, like I said, I am not using the WebViewRenderer anywhere. Maybe one of the nugets is, trying to find out...

Comment: you may be using a nuget that does reference it

Comment: that's what I said.